# efficiently list items in tuples starting at end

Tags: python, tuples

I'd like to list the items in a tuple in Python starting with the back and go to front.
Similar to:

```
foo_t = tuple(int(f) for f in foo)
print foo, foo_t[len(foo_t)-1] ...
```

I believe this should be possible without Try ...-4, except ...-3.
Thoughts? suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `print tuple(reversed(foo_t))`, or use `list` in lieu of `tuple`, or

```
print ' '.join(str(x) for x in reversed(foo_t))
```

and many variants.  You could also use `foo_t[::-1]`, but I think the `reversed` builtin is more readable.

Comment: Wow. I'm always impressed by the number of things Python has built in. This worked out well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, a general tip: in Python you never need to write `foo_t[len(foo_t)-1]`.  You can just write `foo_t[-1]` and Python will do the right thing.

To answer your question, you could do:

```
for foo in reversed(foo_t):
    print foo, # Omits the newline
print          # All done, now print the newline
```

or:

```
print ' '.join(map(str, reversed(foo_t))
```

In Python 3, it's as easy as:

```
print(*reversed(foo_t))
```

Comment: foo_t[len(foo_t)-1] -- oops I guess I was getting jumbled as I was writing. I was thinking of how to comparing some count with < len(foo_t). Thank you.